# How to learn how to find sum of odd elements of matrix in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to write a C program to find the sum of the odd elements of the matrix of m*n order.

Would you please recommend some sites or videos to learn functions, structures, arrays and strings, data types of C programming in a much easy and effective way?

Comment: I expect Microsoft's animated Mr. Clippy should pop here, which says "it looks like you want to someone else to do your homework. Do you want me to help you draft a cheat request on Stack Overflow"?

Comment: Not at all ,sir. Would you please recommend some sites or videos to learn functions, structures,arrays and strings,data types of c programming in a much easy and effective way. If you will do so, it would be your greatness towards me. Thank you..

Comment: I've made a suggested amendment to your question. It is still off-topic, but at least now readers will know you want help rather than someone to do it for you. I don't myself use C, so I cannot help, but you _might_ get some suggestions in the comments. (It is a good idea to read the Help section, in particular How To Ask, to know what questions are a good fit here).

Comment: Flagged as off-topic, as SO is not a place to ask for books and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a variable initialized to 0 then you need to go through each     line  and for each element in that line you check it's parity , if it is odd (element%2==1) then you add it to the sum .

```
int i,j,s = 0;
for ( j=0;i<matrix_height;j++) // for each line
  for ( i=0;i<matrix_width;i++) // for each element in that line
     if(matrix[i][j]%2==1)
s+= matrix[i][j];
```

you need to learn using nested loops that is the main topic of this problem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.